# Bitnami Redmine

Tags: redmine, bitnami

I'm using Bitnami redmine 1.3.1 (upgraded it to 1.3.2) and due to some reason, Mongrels keep dying after few hours.

Her'e another thread mentioning a similar issue
http://bitnami.org/forums/forums/redmine/topics/mongrels-dying-after-few-hours

Due to this, though redmine service is running - I cannot load redmine login page.

Is anyone else facing a similar issue?

Comment: Which platform are you using? Could you check the redmine log file at "apps/redmine/log/production.log"? Try to open the "Manager" tool to see if the servers are running. Do you have any plugin installed?

Comment: Well not sure if this was the problem. I had installed advanced roadmap plugin. And soon as created a milestone, redmine became extremely slow. I had installed redmine on a mac. Once I removed advanced roadmap plugin everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

[BitNami Redmine](http://bitnami.com/stack/redmine) uses Apache with Passenger by default on OS X and Linux. On Windows, the default configuration is Apache with two Thin servers.

Check the plugins that you installed on top of your Redmine application, some of them are only compatible with specific Redmine versions.